# Is there a single word or phrase for "excessive humility disproportionate to ability or achievement"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I am writing a small biographical article  about a long-deceased local doctor who served the poor people of this land meritoriously in the 1930's, and have composed this paragraph:

> Dr.P was a medical giant and also a saint who thought himself just an unremarkable person; everyone was surprised at his **excessive humility.** For example, he politely refused a prestigious award in 1960 saying that "a mediocre physician like me, by no means a medical luminary nor even a special credit to the community, should not be awarded this honor for simply practicing his profession." On another occasion he told a friend:"I am highly overrated: all my achievements were fortuitous considering my ability; I just got lucky!"

I am concerned that "excessive humility/modesty" will be misunderstood as ***[false modesty](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/false_modesty)*** when what I really mean is excessive humility disproportionate to ability or achievement, as in these real life examples:

(1) One of the greatest [ghazal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghazal) singers, who performed in my home city 2 years ago, told the adoring audience:

> "I am just a small and humble singer. Your love has elevated me to such a high position.

(2) In an interview after playing one of the greatest batting innings in [cricket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket) history and making a huge personal score that led his team to an improbable victory, a great Indian batsman said:

> "I am only a supporting batsman in this team of great players. I just wanted to occupy the crease, play out a lot of  time and score runs whenever it was safe to do so. My friend who is a great batsman was very supportive from the other end. I am more happy that my team won this Test match."

This is not false modesty but real and profound expression of humility from a great achiever. In short, the doctor persistently and genuinely considered himself ordinary & mediocre when it was so obvious to others that his achievements and services were extraordinary. "Almost a sense of unworthiness which was very surprising", someone said. It's this sense that I am trying to highlight in my sentence. Is there a single word or phrase that conveys that meaning?

Research done: none of the [synonyms of humility](https://www.google.com/search?q=humility+thesaurus&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&) at Thesaurus.com, Merriam-Webster and Collins Dictionary seem to precisely express my meaning. What comes closest is the adjective **self-effacing** and also the noun **self-abnegation**, which carry some negative tones and may not be appreciated by the home audience, which reveres this legendary doctor.

Sample sentence for SWR (will not be used in this exact way in my article but is illustrative here of the word I seek):

> Dr.P was characterised by excessive humility disproportionate to his high ability and achievements: everyone was surprised by this ______________

Note: adjectival forms are also welcome if the word or phrase doesn't have an appropriate noun form; I shall rewrite my sentence accordingly.

Comment: What's wrong with "humility"?  Humility is the *underestimation* or downplaying of your own importance, so you don't need a special word for people who are humble despite being important.  "He was humble despite his high ability: everyone was surprised by this humility"

Comment: Humility as such is not something to be very surprised by @JeffUK. Many persons express humility. I need to convey the sense of ***excessive*** "disproportionate" humility without using negative-sounding words that may possibly annoy the home audience.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'disproportionate humility'.   Someone with great importance who believes that are not really important at all is humble.  If God himself came to Earth and said "I didn't really do anything,  you guys deserve all the credit" He would be being humble.  and that's a perfectly valid use of the word! You could use a modifier like 'Great humility' or 'Incredible humility'

Comment: I may disagree that humility *can* be disproportionate but thanks for the "modifier" suggestion that follows @JeffUK.

Comment: English Student  .. the word excessive is confusing the issue... it is negative of course because of what it means.. no doubt: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/excessive More than is necessary, normal, or desirable; immoderate.

Comment: Yes, that's why I want a better option. I am trying to express that the doctor was ***far too humble*** given his great ability and services to society @Tom22 -- as in, *how can he consider himself so ordinary when he is so obviously extraordinary?* Mere "humility" doesn't cover it, I think.

Comment: @EnglishStudent  coming back to this one,  I still think the other comments are on track in a number of ways saying 'humble' is the right word, excessive does not apply and oddly, I think you also but your thumb on it in the coment "humility .. is not something to be surprised by.  Truly, when someone acts with a bearing that understates their accomplishments humble is the right word in connection.  There is a difference between a "humble nature" and "professional humility" or  humilty about his leadership in the field  etc.  You may mean both types of humble .. then use it twice

Comment: I think that "no one could help notice his professional humility'  rather than "surpised by"  "impressed by his humilty " is a more positive type of "surprise" .. "I am impressed"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. "Impressed" is a very good option. I think a couple of anecdotes that will follow that paragraph in the article are needed for readers to understand how the doctor's humility was 'excessive' @Tom22. I will edit the question to include this "for example" section. In short, the doctor persistently and genuinely considered himself ordinary & mediocre when it was so obvious to others that his achievements and services were extraordinary. "Almost a sense of unworthiness which was very surprising", someone said. It's this sense that I'm trying to highlight in my sentence.

Comment: Edited Q to include anecdotal examples. If no appropriate substitute word is found I shall go with "too humble" @Tom22, as in *"Dr.P was a medical giant and also a saint who thought himself just an unremarkable person; everyone thought that he was **too humble**. For example, he politely refused a prestigious award in 1960 saying that "a mediocre physician like me, etc."* This has the added advantage that "too" is often used in Indian English as an intensifier like "very" and does not have negative connotations for the ordinary reader.

Comment: @JeffUK I disagree very much with that. If the doctor in question had accepted the award and mentioned how so much of his success as a doctor came down to fortuitous circumstances more than innate brilliance, that would be humility. Actually declining the award and saying he wasn’t a credit to the medical community is absolutely disproportionate. It’s not only humble, but _self-abasing_. Putting oneself down needlessly is not humility.

Comment: You are right of course, thanks @Janus Bahs Jacquet; may I only clarify that I had not edited in that anecdote about the award [which will appear in the actual article] at the time of JeffUK's comment.

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus? Mine gave me this list.  They are not synonyms. Each one carries its own particular sense. Take your pick. noun humbleness, modesty
shyness
abasement
bashfulness
demureness
diffidence
docility
lowliness
meekness
mortification
nonresistance
obedience
obsequiousness
passiveness
reserve
resignation
self-abasement
self-abnegation
servility
sheepishness
subjection
submissiveness
subservience
timidity
timorousness
unobtrusiveness
unpretentiousness
fawning
inferiority complex
lack of pride

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensive list @WS2. Many of those words are appropriate here. What surprised me was that most of those nouns (except modesty) would strike my audience as negative in implication when applied to their favorite doctor. What I like best: modesty, unpretentiousness and lack of pride. An even more suitable word in context that your list has reminded me of is ***selflessness*** as in "Dr.P was so *selfless* that he actually considered himself a mediocre physician, when in fact he was one of our greatest doctors of the 20th century."

Answer (score 1):

**modesty**

> 1. The state or quality of being moderate in the estimation of one's own abilities, accomplishments, or value.
> 2. Reserve or propriety in speech, dress, or behavior:
> 3. The state of being unostentatious or moderate in size, quantity, or range:

As in:

> Dr. P was characterized by excessive humility disproportionate to his
>   high ability and achievements. Everyone was surprised by how
>   **modest** he was. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/modesty)

Th OP can rewrite my sentence accordingly!

Comment: new word choice for my answer

Comment: I like that as well, thanks again @lbf! Shouldn't it be "Everyone was surprised by how *modest* he was?"

Comment: @EnglishStudent - so edited

Comment: The answer still shows "modesty" rather than the adjective "modest" which is required in that example @lbf: I have edited it if you don't mind.

Comment: @EnglishStudent  no problemo!

Comment: OK fine @lbf. If no other suitable term emerges I shall use "too modest" and/or "extreme humility" as my term(s) of choice as in *"Dr.P was a medical giant and also a saint who thought himself just an unremarkable person; everyone thought him **too modest** and was surprised at his extreme humility."*